# How to use all cpu cores vs2010 winform design?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 and my computer have 4 cpu cores. 
In a c# project when I'm in "Design" mode on a Form and I... select a control...go to its property page...change its text and hit Enter, then it takes a lot of time cause VS uses only 1 cpu core for the recalculation. It takes about 20 sec to change a button text. Can I configure VS to use all 4 CPU cores?

Comment: There is no simple "flip a swtich" way to do this. You need to show us the calcuation you are doing and we may be able to help. I recommend you go read the free book from Microsoft "[Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)" to learn some of the basics.

Comment: When i select one of my 200 controls from my from and change its text, the  VS apply my modifications and it takes 20 sec to redraw the form. What more info do you need? im not doing programming

Comment: Can you [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21957869/edit) to include some code showing how you are editing your text.

Comment: Modified original post as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, no you can not use more than one thread to make the UI update itself quicker.

However 20 seconds to update 200 controls is extremely slow, that is 100 ms per control! I would recommend running a [code profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) on your code so you can see what is actually causing the slowness when you update some text and fixing that part of the program.